# Can i create a table with 2 foreign keys? These 2 foreign keys are 2 primary keys of 2 different tables

Tags: database, database-design

I am planning to create a table with 2 foreign keys. These 2 foreign keys reference 2 primary keys of 2 different tables. However, one of the two foreign keys may be null due to business reasons. So can I create this table?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? The SQL syntax might differ slightly between different database products

Comment: I am designing a table, but I have not yet implemented it on any specific database. I want to ask the feasibility of the above design

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing which RDBMS this is for, the syntax might be slightly off - but sure, you can definitely have two foreign keys in a single table, referencing two other tables - and sure, one of them can be nullable. The *referenced* primary key columns in the two master tables you reference typically however **cannot** be NULL; most RDBMS do **NOT allow** `NULL` in a primary key.

In SQL Server, you would set it up something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_YourFirstForeignKey
        FOREIGN KEY (YourFirstColumn) REFRENCES dbo.MasterTable1(Column1);

ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_YourSecondForeignKey
        FOREIGN KEY (YourSecondColumn) REFRENCES dbo.MasterTable2(Column2);
```

`YourTable` would have to have two columns (assuming `INT` datatype here - adapt as needed):

```
YourFirstColumn INT NOT NULL,
YourSecondColumn INT NULL
```

The `YourFirstColumn` is a must-have column, while `YourSecondColumn` can be null.

And of course - you could also define and include those FK constraints directly into your  `CREATE TABLE` statement, if you prefer to do that.